# How to make that custom shape-soft edge gradient in PhotoShop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, behance

I'm just trying to learn some new stuff and found [this](https://www.behance.net/gallery/78651913/Ponrom?tracking_source=search-all%7Cgradient%20topography). How can I make that sort of gradient on a custom shape with those smooth edges?

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you write what you tried and why you think it didn't worked out?

Comment: Sure, I've used the gradient overlay on the layer style window, and found out I can just do some basic gradient. I'm not really sure of what else I can do, I'm really newbie on design.

Answer (score 1):

Try experimenting with the Blur Gallery filters in Photoshop - there are several kinds to choose from, such as Tilt Shift, Irish Blur, Path Blur etc.

The examples below began as a simple wave shape over a black background

[image]

Here's an example using the Iris Blur tool

[image]

You can go crazy with the Path Blur tool

[image]

Answer (score 0):

well i think you will to select the border first
select / modify / border
give it a 20 px ( in my opinion )
and then choose gradient from the to color involve
if the pic is green and the backgroud is blue
so choose this 2 color when you do grdient
good luck
erez

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/114658)